# Issues with validation of signup form

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm adding a validation to my sign up form , the validate code is working but the errors don't shows up in the page

**PHP code**

```
 public function postSignUp(Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'=> 'required|email|unique:users',
            'first_name'=> 'required|max:120',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
            ]);

        $email = $request['email'];
        $first_name = $request['first_name'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

        $user =  new User();

        $user->email = $email;
        $user->first_name = $first_name;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();

        Auth::Login($user);

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
```

**Welcome.blade.php code**

```
@section('content')
@if(count($errors) > 0)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

the php code is working because if i tried to register with an email that already taken it wont register but the error is that errors are not showing up in the welcome page

Comment: Can you post your Controller function?

Comment: Hi! Please don't put question text as the title, I've proposed a edit for you so you can see what I mean :)

Comment: @ImAtWar I've posted check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the error messages back to the view. 
As stated at [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#working-with-error-messages)

```
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect('dashboard')->withErrors($validator);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking with the function count($errors) but that is an object and it will always enter the condition since you are counting the object not the list itself.

**Replace** @if(count($errors) > 0) **with** @if(!empty($errors->all()))